# Does hurling the flame from Produce Flame cost another action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

> **Produce Flame** *1 action, 10 minutes*
>   A flame appears in your hand, harming neither you or your equipment. It sheds bright light in a 10-foot radius and dim light for an additional 10 feet. The spell ends if you dismiss it as an action or if you cast it again.
>
> You can hurl the flame at a creature within 30 feet of you. Make a ranged spell attack. On a hit, the target takes 1d8 fire damage. The spell then ends.

The spell does not state whether attacking using the produced flame is a part of the spell, or requires another action on the next turn.

What happens if:

1. I cast Produce Flame, and wants to attack in this turn. Can I do this?
2. I cast Produce Flame, and later wants to attack in that turn. Do I consume an action, or it's "free" because I've spent an action to cast Produce Flame earlier?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Hurling the flame can be part of casting the spell, or an action afterwards.

The [current wording](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/produce-flame) of the second paragraph of the spell is (emphasis mine):

> You can also attack with the flame, although doing so ends the spell. **When you cast this spell**, or as an action on a later turn, **you can hurl the flame** at a creature within 30 feet of you. Make a ranged spell attack. On a hit, the target takes 1d8 fire damage.

Comment: can you please clarify, holding onto flame for next turn isnt going to grant an extra action is it? can it be used as bonus action or would that be a second attack?

Comment: @FranciscoDeLaPaz "as an action on a later turn". So to throw the flame, you use your action. You can't take another action, such as Attack or Cast a Spell, on the turn when you throw the flame. It's not a bonus action, and it can't be done as one attack in the Attack actions if you have the Extra Attacks feature.